# Tkinter bind problem

Tags: python, menu, tkinter, bind

I have something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

def _quit():
    root.destroy()

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m, tearoff=0)
m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="Quit", command=_quit, accelerator='Ctrl+Q')

root.bind('<Control-Q>', _quit())
root.bind('<Control-q>', _quit())

root.mainloop()
```

My question is:
"Why `_quit()` always is being called?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are binding with Tkinter you typically do not call the function you wish to bind.

You're supposed to use the line

```
root.bind('<Control-Q>', _quit)
```

instead of

```
root.bind('<Control-Q>', _quit())
```

Take note of the lack of parentheses behind **_quit**.

This code below should work.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")

def _quit(event):
    root.destroy()

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m, tearoff=0)
m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="Quit", command=lambda: _quit(None), accelerator='Ctrl+Q')

root.bind('<Control-Q>', _quit)
root.bind('<Control-q>', _quit)

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

Oops sorry, I only ran the code testing the keyword command for quit in the menu bar. Not the bound key commands. When doing bindings for Tkinter and I'm pretty sure most GUI toolkits, the binding inserts and event argument when the function is called. However the Tkinter command keyword argument does not typicaly insert an event. So you have to compromise by having the command keyword argument "artificially" insert an event argument of None (**lambda: _quit(None)**). This allows you to use one function in both scenarios.

Comment: that was helful, but this code returns an error `TypeError: _quit() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: but, when `def _quit(event=None):
    root.destroy()` then program seem to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Because you're calling it. Don't call it:

```
root.bind('<Control-Q>', _quit)
```